# What does %\n% mean - Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to understand a script but I dont know how %\n% is used, I dont understand why it can stand behind a string -->

```
set getKey=%\n%
for %%# in (1 2) do if %%#==2 (%\n%
  set key=%\n%
  set inKey=%\n%
  set keyTest=%\n%
  ^<^&9 set /p "inKey="%\n%
  if defined inKey (%\n%
    set inKey=!inKey:~0,-1!%\n%
    for %%C in (!args!) do set /a keyTest=1^&if /i !inKey! equ %%~C set key=!inKey!%\n%
  )%\n%
  if not defined keyTest set key=!inKey!%\n%
set draw=%\n%
cls%\n%
for /l %%Y in (0,1,%height%) do echo(!line%%Y!%\n%
echo Speed = !Difficulty! !replay!%\n%
echo Time  = !m!:!s!%\n%`
```

...(it goes further)

what is `cls%\n%` ??

if somebody understands me, please help me

THNX

the whole script -->

http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741

Comment: Is this the whole script? Or there's something missing at the top? I understand there are more lines below, but what about above?

Comment: @dbenham Your batch file is under study here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%\n%` is the expansion of the environment variable `\n`. So you need to look where that is defined.

When you find it there is a comment explaining it:

```
:: define a newline with line continuation
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"
```

What is `LF`?

```
:: define LF as a Line Feed (newline) character
set ^"LF=^

^" Above empty line is required - do not remove
```

So `LF` is being set to a newline character. All that gubbins is just a long-winded way of doing something which is not easy to do in a CMD batch file.

Answer (score 0):

`%\n%` is a normal environment variable.

Run this to see it work:

```
@echo off
set \n=a
set getKey=%\n%
echo "%getkey%"
pause
```

Comment: sorry but if you look -->

Comment: cls%/n%   what is that?